# Postgis performance increase with cluster?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've been reading a few questions on this site and saw quite a few people advocating for creating a cluster function.

So I've decided to test this function to see if there was any notable speed increase. I've used a table with 35,000 points. Both tables have the spatial index but tableb has the cluster

```
create table tableb as select * from tablea

CREATE INDEX tableb_sidx ON tableb  USING gist  (geom);

CLUSTER tableb USING tableb_sidx

select a.*
from tablea a, inventory b
where st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 200)

select a.*
from tableb a, inventory b
where st_dwithin(a.geom, b.geom, 200)
```

Running these st_dwithin queries result in the exact same running time of 1 minute

Am I doing something wrong or does this cluster not apply to every spatial query?

Comment: "PostgreSQL does not allow clustering on PostGIS GIST indices" reference https://postgis.net/docs/performance_tips.html#database_clustering

Comment: @Mapperz I find the postgis docs to be very vague, so how should i create the cluster?

Comment: First the table has to have an index. Then you can re-order using the cluster command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-cluster.html

Comment: @Mapperz that's not entirely true and it's essential people read that source link. If the geom coll is `NOT NULL`, you can cluster. Most of the time, it is not null. Though granted, that's not always the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the research I've done in the past, the effects of spatial fragmentation are measurable at 10k rows, barely perceptible at 100k rows, noticeable at 1m rows, and pronounced at 10m rows. These were worst case models, with randomly distributed data, and 2-5% return sets, so it's likely that the impact of barely fragmented data or with very small return volume would not be noticible without extensive testing (sample sizes large enough to show statistically significant variance).

It seems likely that your performance can be improved, but the issue is not spatial fragmentation.  You should defragment *both* tables(on an attribute index which is spatially correlated, like zipcode or province) **and** run `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` before further testing. After that you should use  `EXPLAIN` to determine the query plan and move forward from there.

Comment: I think it's somewhat dependent on disk io, and work_mem. Though I think all of your numbers are high from my experience. Above 10-15k rows, and I have it on my todo. There are multiple ways to cluster which can have vastly different effects. http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/clusterindex.html